# Given sorted vector find transition from negative to positive

Tags: c++, c++11, search, stl, stl-algorithm

Given a sorted `std::vector<int>`, I would like, using C++11-STD functions, to  find the index where the elements transition from negative to positive.

I am aware that I can implement this using a binary search but I am interested if there is any function in the standard library, similar to the unary`find_if`, which would facilitate this search (maybe in connection with the right lambda expression).

Comment: What's wrong with `std::find_if`?

Comment: @Rakete1111: find_if is linear, but the problem is solvable in LogN time

Comment: @ Armen Tsirunyan True, even besides that I woudnt know how to use find_if in this context

Comment: @user695652: You would use it like this
`auto iter = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind(std::greater<int>(), _1, 0));` which would return an iterator to the first positive element

Comment: The same can be achieved with a lambda: `auto iter = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int x){return x > 0;});`

Comment: Ah right because find_if returns the *first* element matching the condition

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should find the [lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) of 0:

```
auto iter = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0);
```

the resulting iterator will point to the earliest position where you can insert 0 without disrupting the ordering of elements. Similarly, `upper_bound` will return the right-most such iterator.

The runtime of the algorithm is `O(logN)`